# Best way to change the texture of a CombinedImageSampler2D (sampler2D GLSL)?

Tags: c++, glsl, vulkan

I have a Vulkan application that uses a single Graphics Pipeline:

The Graphics Pipeline has a **uniform MVP matrix** inside the vertex shader, and a **uniform sampler2D** in the fragment shader for texturing.

The Graphics Pipeline is used to render a cube, the problem is that I sometimes need to change his texture (outside the RenderPass), but I don't know how to do it.

This forces me to create multiple Descriptor Sets, each one having its own different sampler2D, and then choosing the one I need.

P.S. The sampler of the CombinedImageSampler2D is always the same, I just need a way to change the Image it manages.

Comment: Thanks! I also have thought of a "better" way, I actually didn't need to have separate textures, so I can just stuff everything inside a single texture, and use a uniform vec2 to pass the offsets to the shader, based on what part of the image I need.